# If amazon s3 were banned from my country, can I use DNS to solve this problem

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm now thinking about moving to s3, but I'm still concern about the restriction policy in my country in the future, so I'm wondering if I can use some DNS service or some other way to solve this problem.

Comment: This is a networking issue, not a programming issue.

Comment: It all depends on how the "restriction" is implemented.  Also, even if you are able to bypass it using DNS or something else, you could still get into trouble for it if it's banned...  Would need to know how it is restricted to be able to answer the technical question.  As Lucero says, this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 3):

It's doubtful that DNS can help with this issue.

In general, it's quite difficult to bypass such restrictions if there is an entity that has complete control over the borders of its network. It could be anything - from a government blocking opposition sites for political reasons to a company blocking access to insecure web mail providers for security reasons.

If an entity wants to block a specific service provider, it's easier, more effective and far more efficient to simply block all IP address blocks that belong to that provider. DNS is at a higher level and will not help with this issue.

What would help is an unblocked proxy (relay) or VPN service. You connect to that service and tunnel any connection to your intended service provider through that connection. It could be:

- A proxy server abroad that is not blocked. There are commercial proxy/anonymizer services that may be able to help here, although the most known ones are bound to be blocked too.
- A VPN connection to an unblocked network e.g. a business partner.
- An application such as [Tor](http://www.torproject.org/). This option usually implies a very significant performance drop and should not be used for high data rates (anything above a few KB/sec).

If you use a remote proxy or VPN server you should contact the owners and find out their policy for something like this.