# ip masking a specific ip address

Tags: security, web, ip-address, ip, detection

so suppose I detect a user's ip using some code to perform restrictions....

is there a way for a user to circumvent this by arbitrarily setting their ip to any ip they want anytime they want (eg. via proxy server or something) hence allowing them to choose a specific ip to be displayed when I detect it

Comment: You answered your own question.  Yes, a determined user/hacker can use a proxy / anonymizing proxy to get around your IP restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several [tunneling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunneling_protocol) and [proxy-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) techniques that will effectively present a different IP address for any HTTP requests than the one belonging to the originating computer. I have mentioned several methods in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527345/determine-if-user-is-using-proxy/4527380#4527380) answer, as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482304/if-amazon-s3-were-banned-from-my-country-can-i-use-dns-to-solve-this-problem/4482456#4482456). In many cases it is actually impossible to tell apart a relayed connection from the real thing...

In general you cannot *forge* the source of a TCP connection on the Internet to be an arbitrary address for a number of reasons, some of which are:

- TCP is a stateful protocol and packets go back and forth even in order to establish the connection. Forging an IP source address means that you cannot get *any* packets back.
- Some ISPs will drop packets generated within their own network that do not have a source IP within the proper subnet. This is usually done at the client connection level to protect the ISP network and prevent random packets from leaking client information to the Internet due to simple misconfiguration issues client-side.
- ISP filters will also prevent users from just setting an arbitrary IP - if not for any other reason, then just because ISPs *sell* connections with static IP addresses at significantly higher prices and having users set their own IPs would spoil that. Not to mention the mess that would result if there could be IP conflicts among the clients of an ISP...

So in general you cannot just spoof the source of a TCP connection. You have to use an intermediate computer to relay the connection.

Keep in mind, however, that motivated and experienced attackers may have at their disposal botnets that consist of millions of compromised computers belonging to innocent users. Each and every one of those computers could theoretically be used as a connection relay, thus allowing a potential attacker quite a wide variety of IP addresses to chose from.

The bottom line is that simple IP-based checks and filters cannot in any form ensure the legitimacy of a connection. You should be using additional methods to protect your service:

- HTTPS and proper user accounts.
- Extensive logging and monitoring of your service.
- Intrusion detection systems and automatic attack responders (be careful with those - make sure you don't lock *yourself* out!).

We cannot really provide a more concrete answer unless you tell us what service you are providing, what restrictions you want to apply and what kind of attacks you are so worried about...

Comment: can the ip be arbitrary though...so for instance if I'm an attacker and I specifically want to set the ip to 223.222.3.1, is there a way for me to specifically set the proxy so that it will display that IP

Answer (score 0):

Sort of - as you mentioned, proxies are a risk, however it makes life a wee bit harder for the attacker so it is still worth using IP bans.

Monitor your logs, automate alerts and if attacks come from another IP - ban it too. If you make life hard enough for an attacker they may give up.